# Is there a difference between joules of energy per coulomb and volts?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, voltage, dimensional-analysis, power

There is a question in my textbook:

> A current of $7\ \mathrm{A}$ goes through the heating element in a hair-drier. The voltage of the heating element is $240\ \mathrm{V}$.
>
> b) How many joules of energy does each coulomb supply to the element as it goes through?

I understand this is a simple problem.

So it's 240 volts. Can this just be changed to 240 joules per coulomb? Is voltage and energy per unit charge related?

Comment: I fixed up some confusion between units and the quantities they measure in the edit I made.

Comment: Joules express energy, Coulombs charge, and Amps current (charge/second). Can you take it from here?

Comment: Two points differ in potential by one volt if the work done in taking one coulomb between those two points is one joule.

Comment: You're absolutely correct

Answer (score 1):

$1$ J is the work done in taking 1 C between a potential difference of 1 V. Then, since the electric work is $qU$, $1\, J = 1\, C\cdot V$, or $1\,V = 1\,J/C$: you were right.